# How send different client certificates on different requests with a single instance of HttpClient in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

The recommendation for `HttpClient` is to [reuse a single instance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shacorn/2016/10/21/best-practices-for-using-httpclient-on-services/). But from the API, it looks like the way to add certificates is on the instance, not per request. If we add two certificates, how can we make sure that "cert 1" is only sent to "one.somedomain.com", for example?

```cs
//A handler is how you add client certs (is there any other way?)
var _clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

//Add multiple certs
_clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert1);
_clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert2);
_clientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;


//Pretend this is our long-living HttpClient
var client = new HttpClient(_clientHandler);

//Now if we make a post request, will both certs be used?
using (HttpResponseMessage response = _client.PostAsync("https://one.somedomain.com", content).Result)
{
    //...elided...
 }
```

Comment: It seems, that you need to implement you own `HttpClientHandler` with desierable behavior.

Comment: I think creating new HttpClient per server would save the day. You can put them in a dictionary where the key is server base address

Comment: @KrivitskiyGrigoriy That might be the only option, but I wonder if that would add too much extra processing on every request or if there's a way to keep it fast? Also, would you know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. End of year a lot of work.
Yo can try to implement somthing like this:

```
public class CustomHttpHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, X509Certificate> _certMap;

    public CustomHttpHandler():base()
    {
        _certMap = new Dictionary<string, X509Certificate>() { { "server1name", new X509Certificate("cert1") }, { "server2name", new X509Certificate("cert2") } };
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string serverName = request.RequestUri.Host;
        if (ClientCertificates.Contains(_certMap[serverName]))
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
                throw;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ClientCertificates.Clear();
            ClientCertificates.Add(_certMap[serverName]);

            try
            {
                var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just an idea, not tested it.
Or, alternatively you can use `Headers` collection in `RequestMessage` instance.
This article cover the topic: https://damienbod.com/2019/09/07/using-certificate-authentication-with-ihttpclientfactory-and-httpclient/

Comment: Is there any way to dispose Dictionary values before the exit.

Comment: I believe this solution is not thread safe

Answer (score -3):

That is the recommendation, however, you can use "using" statements.

Once HttpClient is an IDisposable, you should use something like

```
using(var client = new HttpClient(_clientHandler))
{
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: This is specifically NOT recommended by Microsoft and will introduce performance problems, memory leaks, and connection handle leaks